# tkinter yes/no message box that must be answered

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I display a message box that prevents the user from clicking anything in another tkinter window, until yes/no has been clicked.

Comment: have you researched the standard dialog boxes provided by tkinter?

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet for a kick off:

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

app = Tkinter.Tk()

choice = tkMessageBox.askquestion("Yes/No", "Are you sure?", icon='warning')
print('User chosen: {}'.format(choice))

app.mainloop()
```